# Can't login to API

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-6

I am trying to build my API Auth from scratch and not able to log users in.
I think the problem is with the token driver but not sure.

After doing some more search, I have found that [Laravel API docs.](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.html) which looks like, every function in the source of laravel I used `Auth::guard('api')->setUser();` which makes the check function return true but still fell that something is wrong since after 12 hour of inactivity still the check function returns `true`

```php
Auth::guard('web')->login($user); // this line works perfectly
Auth::guard('api')->login($user); 
// this line return an error undefined function login
```

---

Here is my registration controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hash;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use App\User;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $req)
    {
      $this->validator($req->all())->validate();
      $data = $this->extractData($req);
      $user = $this->create($data);
      $token = $user->addAPIToken();
      $this->guard()->setUser($user);
      echo $this->guard()->check();
      return response()->json(['token' => $token]);

    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
      return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:12|string|confirmed'
      ]);
    }

    protected function extractData(Request $req){
      return [
        'name' => $req->name,
        'email' => $req->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($req->password)
      ];
    }

    protected function create(array $data){
      return User::create($data);
    }

    protected function addToken(User $user){
      $token = Str::random(60);
      $user->update(['api_token' => hash('sha256', $token)]);
      return $token;
    }

    protected function guard(){
      return Auth::guard('api');
    }

}
```

and this is how I have created my token

```
public function addAPIToken()
    {
      do {
        $token = Str::random(60);
        $this->api_token = hash('sha256', $token);
      } while ($this->where('api_token', $this->api_token)->exists());
      $this->save();
      return $token;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how to use api ?

Comment: If the API is all your code, you should show us that code, as it is that code that is throwing an error !

Comment: Only [SessionGuard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L405) implements a `login` method. You need to send a token to login via the default `'api'` [guard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php)

Comment: updated my question and provided the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests. In your "config/auth.php" you can see something like this:

> ```
> 'guards' => [
>     'web' => [
>         'driver' => 'session',
>         'provider' => 'users',
>     ],
>
>     'api' => [
>         'driver' => 'passport',
>         'provider' => 'users',
>     ],
> ],
> ```

It means that for Passport you will not use Sessions.
Basically Laravel Passport waits for requests with "email" and "password" for authentication users. After retrieval, if the password that came in the request matches the password of the retrieved record (with decryption of course), then system generates a token and send it as a response with the 200 status code. If the password mismatch, then it sends the appropriate error message with 422 status code. This is a normal way.
But you can imitate the token for yourself with this:

> ```
> public function loginUserViaPassport($user_id) {
>     $user = User::findOrFail($user_id); // some user
>     $app_name = 'Laravel'; // or config('app.name');
>     $token = $user->createToken($app_name . ' Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
>     return response()->json([
>         'token' => $token,
>     ], 200);
> }
> ```

So here you can use 4th line of this block for yourself.

**UPDATE BELOW**

Excuse me for misunderstanding. I just written about Passport actually. But the logic is the same: for example if you write the RESTful API with JSON requests-responses for Laravel app (like Passport, which based on OAuth2 system), then you can't authenticate users with traditional sessions. If you lose the DB, you'll lose also authenticated users too. So for authentication you (as a client)

1. need to send your credentials (email/username and password) to the server (as back-end laravel app)
2. server will check that according with current user ID (user will be found using sent email)
3. if checking was successful, it will return the token (which will have expiration time for most cases), else it will return info about invalid credentials with appropriate status code
4. if checking was successful, further that client can access their private info only with that token, which will kept in Requests Header (e.g. for Bearer authentications)

These are the shortest guide about RESTful API and I hope this will help to understand that you can't do that login imitation as you want with something like this:
Auth::guard('api')->login($user);

Comment: Passport isn't in question here.

Comment: Have updated the answer

Comment: that's what i'm trying to do but looks like there is something missing , i 've updated the question with more information